Understanding the MPI ping pong example
I'm following this tutorial https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/
int ping_pong_count = 0;
int partner_rank = (world_rank + 1) % 2;
while (ping_pong_count < PING_PONG_LIMIT) {
    if (world_rank == ping_pong_count % 2) {
        // Increment the ping pong count before you send it
        ping_pong_count++;
        MPI_Send(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("%d sent and incremented ping_pong_count "
               "%d to %d\n", world_rank, ping_pong_count,
               partner_rank);
    } else {
        MPI_Recv(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("%d received ping_pong_count %d from %d\n",
               world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);
    }
}

From my understanding, in MPI each process run the same code in parallel.
So for process0, ping_pong_count went from 0 to 10, so the output for process0 is
#ping_pong_count = 0, so ping_pong++ is 1
0 sent 1 to 1
#ping_pong = 1, go to the else logic
0 received 2 from 1
...

? like this?
But process1 didn't send anything to process0? so MPI_Recv won't cause an error?
If from process1's point of view, it sends something to process0, but MPI_Send happens multiple times when ping_pong_count % 2 == 1 for process1, so what ping_pong_count are being transferred between process0 and process1?

Rank 1 starts receiving 1 from rank 0, and then send 2 to rank 0

@GillesGouaillardet Thank you, I see. So does this strictly follow this order: in the second loop of process0, it goes to the else logic, it runs MPI_Recv so it requires process1 to go into the first loop and it is 1 receives 1 from 0, and then process1 goes into the second loop and 1 sends 2 to 0, and then process1 goes to the third loop in which ping_pong_count==2 so it goes to else logic and runs MPI_Recv, so MPI goes backwards to run the second loop of process0, which is 0 receives 2 from 1?

Ranks run independently. At the beginning, rank 0 sends 1 to 1, and 1 receive from 0.

@Gilles Gouaillardet  MPI_Recv and MPI_Send won't affect each rank to run independently? but it seems the value of ping_pong_count is changed by this in each rank's loop?

The value is increased right before being sent
